# Recovering licensed windows from bad hard disk

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, license

I have a Acer laptop which has Win XP installed. It's hard disk has gone bad. The laptop did  not come with a recovery disk but instead had a Windows recovery partition on its hard disk. If I buy a new hard disk while the rest of the components remain the same how can I recover and use the licensed Windows which came with the laptop ?

Comment: You may need to contact Acer for the Software Recovery Discs

Comment: The product key installed by ACER will do you no good, it is a Volume License Key which will not activate if used. Use the product key from the sticker or order Recovery discs from Acer as suggested by kobaltz and Jake223.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a license code on the bottom of your laptop, on a sticker. You should be able to call  Microsoft or Acer and tell them about your problem. With that license code, and a copy of Windows xp, you should be able to reinstall on another drive.

[This discussion](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/254178-45-license-question) may also help you.